# Malformed HTTP requests on rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, http, rest, xmlhttprequest

I'm getting this occacional error from my rails app:

**ActionController::MethodNotAllowed: Only get, put, and delete requests are allowed.**

I think it's caused by a malformed HTTP request (in this case a DELETE request) caused by the client browser... Maybe?

The URL that triggers this action it's like:

**https://domain.com/resource/id/resource/id/resource/id.js?item_id=xxx**

Which is generated by a helper like:

```
link_to_remote('delete', :url => resource_path(:id => @resource, :item_id => xxx, :format => :js), :method => :delete)
```

In some remote cases this crashes, I suspect that this happens only in IE (even IE8)...

If it is the case, what would be a solution? it supossed this should work in all browsers...

What do you suggest, guys?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: My guess is that something is sending a POST to your URL without the hidden parameter that tells Rails it should be treated as a DELETE. Since the route doesn't accept POST Rails raises that error. You could loosen the restriction on the route so that it does accept POST, but that wouldn't be very RESTful.

Comment: Hi Chris, actually in some cases it's sends via POST, apparently the client browser ignores completely the AJAX request, but i don't know why, that's my doubt

Answer (score 0):

You can emulate a DELETE request with define the _method params to 'delete' and POST your request

Comment: Hi, I am currently doing that, the link looks like:

<a onclick="new Ajax.Request('/resource/id/resource/id.js?item_id=xxx', {asynchronous:true, evalScripts:true, method:'delete'}); return false;" href="#"><img border="0" src="/images/delete.gif?1252605364" alt="Trash"></a>

Comment: That usually works, but in some cases -and I don't know why- the request is made via POST method and this launch the exeption.